# CSS Transition is not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have just started learning CSS transitions from [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/). But the code doesn't work. I am executing on Firefox in Ubuntu.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animation</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="image1">
<img  src="image.jpg" height="150" width="150" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#image1 {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

I get only the image but not the transition.
Also, how do I make the transition run on a button click?

Comment: Transition will run once you change some CSS property.

Comment: You need some javascript to run on a button click.

Answer (score 3):

By definition the word "transition" means change of state from one into another. CSS transition thus will only run once you change some CSS property. For example you can change some styles on mouseover with `:hover` pseudo class or by changing class name. For example:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image1');

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
    image.className = image.className === 'active' ? '' : 'active';
};
```

```css
#image1 {
    border: 4px #DDD solid;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#image1:hover,
#image1.active:hover {
    border-color: purple;
    border-width: 4px;
}

#image1.active {
    border-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" id="image1" height="150" width="150" />

<button>Run</button>
```

**Notes**

1). You don't need to define vendor prefixes for transition, since [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) is already pretty good.

2). Of course instead of `all` keyword in transition rule you can define a specific property to animate:

```css
#image1 {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#image1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

3). Read about CSS Transitions more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: You can also specify a set of properties by not using the shorthand: `transition-property: opacity, left, top, height;` - see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#When_property_value_lists_are_of_different_lengths (part of your MDN link)

Comment: It is possible to **fake** a button click with a very long `transition-duration` on the base settings and setting the `transition-duration / delay` to `0` on the `:active` state - See [**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bweFC) Clearly though `buttons` & `clicks` should be handled via JS/JQ

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you change the css values, or there will be nothing to animate.  You can put the values of the image under the :hover selector, like this:

```css
#image1 {
width:20px;
height:20px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#image1:hover {
width:200px;
height:200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animation</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<img  src="image.jpg" height="150" width="150" id="image1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information about animations and for some good practice, visit [W3Scools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).